# Mongoose lean() is turning a number into a timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a prop called `duration` which is declared as a `number` in the mongoose schema with the purpose of storing a duration in seconds:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        ...
        duration: { type: Number, required: true }
        ...
    },
    { timestamps: true },
)
```

After using the method `findOne()` and applying the `lean()` method, the prop `duration` is returned as a timestamp when it was set as a number. **It happens when the number is greater than 1000.**

```
const myVideo = await Models.Video.findOne({ _id: videoId })
            .populate({ path: 'segment', populate: { path: 'type' } })
            .lean()
            .exec()
```

When I set: `{ "duration": 6000 }` I get: `{ "duration": "1970-01-01T00:00:06.000Z" }`

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**

Besides trying to find the source of the issue, this is what I tried in the code:

- I tried upgrading the Mongoose version from **5.9.15** to **5.12.7** to see if a fix was added for this but nothing changed.
- Tried removing the `{ timestamp: true }` from the schema, didn't work either.
- Also tried adding other props or options like `{ lean: true }` but at the end the result wasn't that different because I did stopped getting the timestamp but the returned object was a mongoose document instead of a plain old javascript object.

**MY TEMPORARY SOLUTION**

The temporary solution that I found for this was removing the `lean()` from the chain, but I still couldn't understand what was causing this.